# Getting row index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, row

I have something like this:

```
$("#myTable td").each(function(){
   if($(this).html()=="")
   {    
      rIndex1=$(this).parent().index(); //this always stays "1"
      rIndex2=$(this).rowIndex; //this stays as "undefined"
```

but none of them works. I googled it and all on the answers depend on click events. Here, I am travelling all the table, and if I found a cell which is NULL, then I want to find the row index of this cell. Any method?

EDIT:

```
rIndex=$(this).closest("tr").index(); //returns 1 always
rIndex=this.parentNode.rowIndex;  //returns -1 always
rIndex=$(this).parentNode.rowIndex;  //returns error msg. (I'm trying everything now)
```

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: `$(this).rowIndex` should be `this.parentNode.rowIndex`.

Comment: trying using closet("tr") instead of parent()

Comment: Or `$(this).parent().prop('rowIndex')`.

Comment: ...When you do `$(this)`, it returns a jQuery object that holds the `td` element, and a jQuery object doesn't have a `rowIndex` property. But for that matter, the actual `td` element doesn't have `.rowIndex` either, but the `tr` does, so that's why we use `this.parentNode.rowIndex`.

Comment: ...though `$(this).parent().index()` should work too. Can't tell why it's always `1` without seeing your HTML markup.

Comment: What do you mean by _"...and if I found a cell which is NULL"_?

Comment: @undefined: He must be referring to `$(this).html()==""`. Weird way to put it though.

Comment: If you want to target only empty `td` elements, then change your selector string to this: `$("#myTable td:empty")`

Comment: @cookiemonster It seems to be a XY problem. A selector can select all the `tr`s that have empty cells. `$('tr:has("td:empty")')`

Comment: Regarding your update, jQuery doesn't have a `closet` method. You meant `closest` I'd imagine. And the other one is an error for the reason I explained above. You don't seem to be grasping the difference between a DOM element and a jQuery object.

Comment: @undefined: Yep, there certainly is an element of that here.

Comment: @cookiemonster I fixed it and still it returns "1".

Comment: @WhoCares: It returns `1` or an error? The question still says that `this.parentNode.rowIndex;` gives an error. If it only returns `1`, then the only reason could be that it's the second `tr` inside its parent.

Comment: @cookiemonster it returns 1. no error. for example, if there is an empty cell in the 3rd row, still, rIndex returns value 1.

Comment: @WhoCares: DOM selection questions should be accompanied by the HTML markup. Otherwise we can only speculate about the problem. You're leaving details out. Doing `this.parentNode.rowIndex` should work and not cause any error based on what you've shown.

Comment: Now you say `this.parentNode.rowIndex` is `-1`. That could only be if the row is detached from the `document`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the rows in a `$rows` variable, then find the index of the current `tr` (aka `td` parent) in your cached collection.

```
var $rows = $("#myTable tr");
$("#myTable td").each(function(){
   if($(this).html()=="")
   {    
      rIndex = $rows.index($(this).parent());
   }
});
```